# null is not an object (evaluating 'StripeModule.init')

Tags: react-native, expo

**Troubleshoot**

I have an issue when running my react-native app where the error message was:

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'StripeModule.init')
```

I was using tipsi-stripe module in my react-native app.

I didn't find any topic about this problem on internet.

Comment: Did you got the solution and wrote an Q/A for your problem? A bit weird to not have a problem and post it here together with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Link 'tipsi-stripe' module with react-native by running:

```
react-native link tipsi-stripe;
```

If you have an expo app you need to eject your app first with this command:

```
npm run eject
```

as per OP Quentin Fournier Montgieux's own answer in the question.